# search autosuggest for complex nested hierarchy

Tags: gui-design, search, autocomplete, faceted-search, search-suggestion

I am **not** a professional UX designer, but it's up to me to come up with something for this use case

1. I have 3 facets of search i.e. brands, demographics and locations
2. each facet has a hierarchy list of categories and names belonging to those categories
3. Users should be able to select at any level of the hierarchy and any combination of facets and initiate a search

e.g:
1. brand:(BMW OR Audi) AND demographics:(Male, Young OR Adult) AND location:(New York OR Boston OR Seattle)
2. brand:(Luxury Automobiles) AND location:(United States)

So this is what I came up with, could anyone offer some feedback on this? and if there is a better UX? Is anyone aware of a similar UX real-world implementation for me to check out before heading down this route?

[image: mockup]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I this is a pretty good article that can help you: [8 Design Patterns for Autocomplete Suggestions](https://baymard.com/blog/autocomplete-design).
Also, you can check the functionality that Amazon has, it is a good example to follow.
[image]

- Any other data in the suggestion – such as category - should be styled differently from the suggested search terms;
- Limit the number of results and avoid scroll;
- Highlight the differences.

For an advanced search, you should use a proper filtering and avoid making autosuggest too complex.